# Is there an efficient way to manage references in answers?

Tags: support

I just re-read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101045/what-can-we-learn-about-a-group-by-studying-its-monoid-of-subsets/102657#102657) of mine and noticed I'd made some claims without proper references. I will edit this if I find time, but it will require a bit (not that much of course) of work because I wrote all references as plain text. Is there a way to make references enumerate themselves automatically here as in LaTeX?

Comment: What did you try? (works even on meta, wow)

Comment: @draks I'm sure what I could try. All I did was search meta for "references" and "bibliography", finding nothing relevant. And what works even on meta?

Comment: The WDYT-question! :-)

Comment: @draks Ah, OK. I don't know whether it works or not.

Comment: Me neither, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: not something built-in.

Longer answer: for a work around, you can use-and-abuse the hyperlink function of the MarkDown syntax. In particular, instead of

```
[Displayed Text](Hyper link address)
```

you can use

```
[Displayed Text][linkname]
```

(note the square brackets!) with linkname defined at the end of the post

```
[linkname]: hyperlink address
```

So for your references 1 and 2 in your post, I would write, for example (using the AMS style Author-Year labels)

```
See references [GI84] and [GI84a]. Yada yada. 
This other thing is also proven in [GI84a].
```

(when the link name is the same as the displayed text, you can omit one set of the brackets) and link to the mathscinet portal

```
[GI84]: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=729648
[GI84a]: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=729652
```

Here's what the above snips would look like:

---

See references [GI84](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=729648) and [GI84a](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=729652). Yada yada. This other thing is also proven in [GI84a](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=729652).

Comment: Very nice, thank you!